# Insert words directly to table in db rather than storing in arraylist using Java

Tags: java

I am building an indexing program where I extract a file (PDF) and extract all the words inside and stored it in an `arrayList`. At the same time, I have to define my word token to see what sort of words to be indexed and its rule , hence I stored them in an arrayList so I could replace the regular expression to suit my needs.

Code:

```
public void index(String path) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(path));

    if (!document.isEncrypted()) {
        PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
        String lines[] = pdfFileInText.split("\\r?\\n");
        for (String line : lines) {
            String[] words = line.split(" ");

            for (String word : words) {
                //check if one/more special characters at end of string then remove OR
                //check special characters in beginning of the string then remove

                list.add(word.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", ""));

            }
        }
    }

    String[] words1 = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    String sql = "insert IGNORE into  test.indextable123 values (?,?)";
    preparedStatement = con.connect().prepareStatement(sql);

    for (int i = 1; i < words1.length; i++) {
        preparedStatement.setString(1, words1[i]);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, path);
        preparedStatement.addBatch();

        if (i % 1000 == 0) {
            preparedStatement.executeBatch();
            System.out.print("Add Thousand");
        }
    }

    if (words1.length % 1000 > 0) {
        preparedStatement.executeBatch();
        System.out.print("Add Remaining");
    }

    preparedStatement.close();
    System.out.println("Completed");
}
```

The problem here is if I want to index a file with over 10 million words, it's not resource efficient to store in the arrayList and it's going to throw an `outofmemory exception` too.

At the same time, I need to store it in an array to "replace" with the regular expression as shown in the code. Is there a way to insert the words directly to the db right after extracting while filtering the words to suit the regular expression I need?

Comment: You should stream it and filter it. I am not sure how to get a stream from PDDocument  but I am sure it is possible

Comment: @VeselinDavidov What do you mean by stream?

Comment: Don't add it to the list here `list.add(word.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", ""));` - just chuck it into the DB

Comment: @ScaryWombat Can I just insert right after extracting directly to db without even using any sort of array?

Comment: I don't see why you need the array. Just store it instead of doing `list.add`.

Comment: No arraya / list needed based upon the above code

Comment: Wouldn't this approach call the INSERT to DB many times(equal to the number of words)? I'm not sure if passing the arrayList causes multiple INSERTs or a single INSERT.

Comment: But then I would need to set the regular expression to the "words"

Answer (score 3):

I believe the real problem is how you read the PDF file. You call  `String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);` which loads the text from the whole file into a string. Then you iterate over it and insert into the database. Loading the contents of a file into a string might lead to memory problems that's why we usually use streams (like inputstream,outputstream etc). They provide you with a way to process the file as you read it instead of loading it in a bulk and then process it.

If you check how [PDFTextStripper](https://www.javatips.net/api/PDF-to-unusual-HTML-master/PDF-to-unusual-HTML/src/org/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFTextStripper.java) works you can see the getText method:

```
 public  String getText( PDDocument doc ) throws IOException
    {
        StringWriter outputStream = new StringWriter();
        writeText( doc, outputStream );
        return outputStream.toString();
    }
```

It uses the writeText method which uses an output stream and collects it into a String. 
 So you have several options:

- In order to avoid that memory peak you need to write a custom PDFTextStripper and override some of the methods.For example you can override the writeText method and change it to write into the database.
- You can process the PDF page by page and this way you can limit the load - I believe there is a processPage method that can be used with some modification of your code
- You can make the super cool solution with creating a custom OutputStream that stores stuff directly into the database and pass that to the writeMethod of the PDFTextStripper

I find that last approach to be the most interesting one (even though processing it page by page might be more robust). So I will give an example code which you can use for reference. It still would need some modification to work properly:

First create a custom writer. Something like:

```
class MyDatabaseWriter extends java.io.Writer{

    private StringBuilder lineBuilder=new StringBuilder();
    //DB stuff go here

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        //Close DB Connection 
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public void write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        String newString=new String(cbuf, off, len);
        lineBuilder.append(newString);
        lineBuilder.toString().matches("\\r?\\n");
        String lines[] = lineBuilder.toString().split("\\r?\\n");
        writeLineToDatabase(lines[0]);
        lineBuilder=new StringBuilder(lines[1]);
    }

    private void writeLineToDatabase(String line) {
        // Process your line and add it to the database
    }

}
```

Then move all the database stuff to the writer and in your main class you should have something like:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(path));
PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
tStripper.writeText(document, new MyDatabaseWriter());  //Or if you create an instance in another way
```

The PDFTextStripper extends PDFStreamEngine (not by accident :) so it will pass the stream it reads to the custom writer and you will send it directly to the database. It only store in the memory the current line.

Comment: I still get an error trying to index 10 million records, is there an easier way out?

Comment: I don't mind using a different library to extract the text or any other way to solve this

Comment: Which approach did you try? The basic idea is not to do string processing on all lines but do it in the PDF processing engine. If I were you I would try the third approach and create my own Writer to pass it to the PDF engine. That way the size of the PDF won't matter - you don't load the lines anywhere. It reads and write

Comment: You don't need to extract it but to process it. Extracting would mean storing it somewhere - you need memory for that. Processing would be read-modify-write and if you use java streams you don't store the intermediate result

Comment: I tried your solution above but did not implement this writeText method yet

Comment: What do I need to modify? Sorry i am a bit new to this

Comment: It is easier as code but won't solve the problem (in my opinion at least). You still load the whole file into the memory by calling the getText method. I think the problem here is not how you write to the database (you can easilly write millions of records one by one). The problem is loading a BIG pdf file into the memory

Comment: Well I cannot write your program. You need to modify the custom writer to add stuff in the database (move your code for the database there).

Comment: Leave those method with @override empty? Also if there is 10 million passwords in a file, it will be able to stream and insert to db without out of memory exception correct?

Comment: Why do you need to extend java.io.Writer? Could just import it ?

Comment: Because default writer just writes somewhere. You need a writer that writes to the database

Comment: Perhaps is it possible to extract a certain amount of text from the PDF and keep doing it so it doesn't consume memory?

Comment: That's what the stream would do. If that's hard to understand you can use that library you have chosen to process PDF page by page instead of process it all at once

Comment: Guess that should eliminate the out of memory error? So I need to process page by page?

Comment: I don't say need. I would use the streaming solution. But if that's easier for you you can process page by page

Answer (score 1):

Just store the data in real time.

```
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(path));

    if (!document.isEncrypted()) {

        String sql = "insert IGNORE into  test.indextable123 values (?,?)";

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.connect().prepareStatement(sql);
        try {
            int i = 0;
            PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
            String lines[] = pdfFileInText.split("\\r?\\n");
            for (String line : lines) {
                String[] words = line.split(" ");

                for (String word : words) {
                    // check if one or more special characters at end of string then remove OR
                    // check special characters in beginning of the string then remove

                    preparedStatement.setString(1, word.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", ""));

                    preparedStatement.setString(2, path);

                    preparedStatement.addBatch();
                    ++i;
                    if (i == 1000) {
                        i = 0;
                        preparedStatement.executeBatch();

                        System.out.print("Add Thousand");
                    }
                }

            }
            if (i > 0) {
                preparedStatement.executeBatch();

                System.out.print("Add Remaining");
            }

        } finally {
            preparedStatement.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Completed");
    }
```

UPDATE: to get rid of the `lines` array:

```
    private static final Pattern WORD_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\w+");

...

    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(path));

    if (!document.isEncrypted()) {

        String sql = "insert IGNORE into  test.indextable123 values (?,?)";

        PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.connect().prepareStatement(sql);
        try {
            int i = 0;
            Matcher matcher = WORD_PATTERN.matcher(pdfFileInText);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                String word = matcher.group();
                // check if one or more special characters at end of string then remove OR
                // check special characters in beginning of the string then remove

                preparedStatement.setString(1, word.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", ""));

                preparedStatement.setString(2, path);

                preparedStatement.addBatch();
                ++i;
                if (i == 1000) {
                    i = 0;
                    preparedStatement.executeBatch();

                    System.out.print("Add Thousand");
                }
            }
            if (i > 0) {
                preparedStatement.executeBatch();

                System.out.print("Add Remaining");
            }

        } finally {
            preparedStatement.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Completed");
    }
```

UPDATE 2: Using a custom `Writer` as suggested by @Veselin:

```
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(path));

    if (!document.isEncrypted()) {

        String sql = "insert IGNORE into  test.indextable123 values (?,?)";

        PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        try {
            Writer writer = new Writer(){
                final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
                int i = 0;

                @Override
                public void write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)
                        throws IOException {
                    int end = off + len;
                    for (int i = off; i < end; ++i) {
                        char c = cbuf[i];
                        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
                            buf.append(c);
                        } else if (buf.length() > 0) {
                            processBuf();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void flush() throws IOException {
                }

                @Override
                public void close() throws IOException {
                    if (buf.length() > 0) {
                        processBuf();
                    }
                    if (i > 0) {
                        preparedStatement.executeBatch();
                    }
                }

                private void processBuf() {
                    String word = buf.toString();
                    buf.setLength(0);
                    preparedStatement.setString(1, word);
                    preparedStatement.setString(2, path);
                    preparedStatement.addBatch();
                    ++i;
                    if (i == 1000) {
                        i = 0;
                        preparedStatement.executeBatch();
                        System.out.print("Add Thousand");
                    }
                }
            };
            tStripper.writeText(document, writer);
            writer.close();
        } finally {
            preparedStatement.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Completed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah but  String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document); method  will still load the whole file into the memory as a string which will be a problem for very large files

Comment: @Maurice How will it deal with string lines[] ?

Comment: I don't think I can do anything about it, except move the two lines involving `tStripper ` before the prepareStatement.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: The lines `PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();` and `String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);` could be moved before the `prepareStatement`.

Comment: To avoid the JDBC statement being open during the "stripping".

Comment: You will still need the memory space for the whole text, and for the `lines` array, but you will not need the ArrayList. Note that your could also save a lot of space by avoiding the split,

Comment: I ran out of idea though

Comment: So no need to use solution like what Veselin suggested below?

Comment: @Daredevil it will use a lot less memory than the original version, but it still stores the whole text in a string.

Comment: The question is can I index 10 million passwords in a file without throwing out of memory exception?

Comment: @Daredevil I guess You'll have to try to have an answer to this question. For what is worth, here's a second update using a custom `Writer` as suggested by Veselin. The only data kept in memory (if any) are in the `PDFTextStripper`.

Comment: Cool, for your latest update, it doesn't look at it's using any memory when reading the PDF file, is that right?

Comment: @Daredevil The memory could be used by the stripper

Comment: I am so stressed out, ran out of idea to fix this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184313/discussion-between-daredevil-and-maurice-perry).

Answer (score 0):

To re-iterate, no other array or list is needed

```
String sql = "insert IGNORE into  test.indextable123 values (?,?)";
preparedStatement = con.connect().prepareStatement(sql);
int i = 0;

for (String word : words) {
     word = word.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", "");

    preparedStatement.setString(1, word);
    preparedStatement.setString(2, path);
    preparedStatement.addBatch();

    i++;
    if (i % 1000 == 0) {
        preparedStatement.executeBatch();
        System.out.print("Add Thousand");
    }

}

if (i > 0) {
    preparedStatement.executeBatch();
    System.out.print("Add Remaining");
}

preparedStatement.close();
System.out.println("Completed");
```

Comment: Just a quick question, do I need string lines[] to split the text?

Comment: Yes, you still need to split

Comment: In that case, if there's few millions words inside a file, wouldn't this cause some memory/resource problem for this lines[]?

Comment: @Daredevil Thank you very much

Comment: But you remove the remaining to add batch?

Comment: No, you should keep that

Comment: Could you edit your answer because I am confused why some of my code is remove?

Comment: Cool. You use if(i>0), why not if(words.length % 1000> 0) , that would work too?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221196/how-to-check-whether-prepared-statement-has-some-batches-or-not-before-executeb

Comment: I see. One thing is I noticed there is always a empty string in the first row of the table, where did i make my mistake?

Comment: Only if `word` turns out to be empty.  You could check for this.

Comment: I thought every file I index always has an empty word in the first row

Comment: Is there any way to solve the memory issue without using lines[] and words[] as I still get outofMemory error?

Comment: You can process the PDF file page by page

Comment: That would still take up memory I guess. Veselin's solution look to be promising but I am not sure how to implement that

Comment: How would that be possible?

Comment: @Daredevil Never done it myself, so one has to read the javadocs, search for examples and try writing some code.